# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException despite dependency in pom.xml

Tags: jaxb, java-11, java-14

I know this question has been answered before, but none of the solutions seem to work. I can compile my program and run the jar with jdk-14 without errors. But when I click the part in the program that uses the jaxb-api the error occurs.

This is my module-info.java:

```
...
requires java.desktop;
requires java.xml;
requires java.xml.bind;
requires jcommon;
requires jfreechart;
requires poi;
```

And the corresponding dependencies in my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jfree</groupId>
    <artifactId>jcommon</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.16</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>jfree</groupId>
    <artifactId>jfreechart</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.13</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>3.11</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0-b180830.0359</version>
</dependency>
```

And somehow the error still occurs.

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but eclipse shows the following error in a pop-up window from time to time: An internal error occurred during: "Polling news feeds".
javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext

Comment: You also need `com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-impl`.

Comment: Adding the dependency to the pom.xml didn't change anything. Do I need to also add something to the module-info.java?

Comment: Can you please share the complete stack trace? Especially the "caused by" parts if they exist?